# What type of Exception should SQLAlchemy model raise when an object is not found in DB?

Tags: python, exception, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web-app that uses SQLAlchemy with the Flask framework.

Below is My SQLAlchemy model (simplified):

```
class MyModelA(db.Model):
    a_id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_model_a(cls, a_id):
        try:
            found_a = cls.query.get(a_id)
        except StatementError:  # when a_id is not a 16-character string
            raise SomeException
        else:
            if found_a is None:
                raise SomeException
```

Here is the Flask method that implements the HTTP endpoint which lets users query the database with an `aID`:

```
@app.route('/does_a_exist', methods=['post'])
def does_a_exist():
    try:
        variable_id = request.get_json().get('a_id')
        s = len(variable_id) # None object haven't any length
        MyModelA.get_model_a(variable_id)
    except SomeException:
        return jsonify(goodbye='world'), httplib.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    else:
        return jsonify(hello='world'), httplib.HTTP_200_OK
```

When the `get_model_a()` fails to find the database row with the given `a_id`, I want it to raise an exception (`SomeException`) which will be caught by the `does_a_exist()` which will respond to the user with a `404`.

My question is: Which Exception class is most suitable to be used in place of `SomeException`?? Can someone recommend one? I'm a SQLAlchemy newbie but I know Django well. In Django I would have raised an `ObjectDoesNotExist` Exception. What is the corresponding SQLAlchemy exception I should use here?

Comment: Accepted. But I actually want the `get_model_a()` to raise an exception when it doesn't find a matching ID. What kind of exception should I raise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to create your own exception class for this error, the `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound` should suit your purposes.

The docs describe the exception as:

> A database result was required but none was found.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.NoResultFound

---

SQLAlchemy already has this feature built in with the `.one()` method where it either returns exactly one result or raises an `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound` exception.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.one